# SQL Between in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How Do I update the same query in tableau ? Thanks

```
   where ClaimOpenDate BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())), 0) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Parameter` in the Custom SQL Query. 
[Take a look at this post.](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-17869)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())` with `DATEADD('year', -1, TODAY())` in Tableau. Similarly, the `DATEDIFF()` function also exists in Tableau.
So the overall code would look like:

```
IF ClaimOpenDate BETWEEN ___ AND ___ THEN ____ END.
```